# test MQTT behaviours and events emitted

Tags: asynchronous, elixir, mqtt, publish-subscribe, mqtt-vernemq

I need to test MQTT behaviors and events emitted by MQTT. E.g whenever I(mock device) publish to MQTT, the Handler gets called by it with valid params(tested this with iex but needs to automate the process) and I performs some actions on the data.

Steps:

1. installed mqqt via docker container
2. added tortoise dependency to my elixir project
3. and added basic listner
4. and tried in console and listen successfully

```rb
Tortoise.publish(:client_id, "d", "my msg" , qos: 0).
```

Note: I tried to use `mock` and `mox` libraries for listening but unable to capture the call event

Question/issue:
[MQTT](https://vernemq.com/%20Mqtt) listens to events(some device publish events to MQTT server) and MQTT calls an elixir listener associated with it. I need to test this behavior: Lets say listener get called by MQTT within 10 seconds. How do I check inside test cases that this method/listener has been called within 10 seconds(with correct params) after I initiate a publish to MQTT

Library: https://github.com/gausby/tortoise

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please update the question, explicitly showing what had you tried and have you got stuck.

Comment: @mudasobwa Does the question makes sense now

Comment: “in ten seconds” or “within ten seconds”?

Comment: @mudasobwa it is within 10 seconds